# What is causing the error between these two .bindPopup?

Tags: leaflet, popup

The below popup works properly displaying "Neigh_Name" (a name such as "Main") and "2020 Total Population" (a string comprised of numbers '234273' etc).

```
layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.Neigh_Name+"<br>"+feature.properties["2020 Total Population"])
```

However, when using the below..

```
layer.bindPopup(feature.properties["2020 Total Population"])
```

I get the error: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Can someone explain what is happening in the backend and why these two lines of code differ and the latter ultimately fails? I'm trying to learn why certain things occur to avoid future issues.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very probably the `bindPopup` method behaves unexpectedly when passing a number as content (your 2nd line), whereas it happily accepts a string argument (as in your 1st line).

Simply make sure to convert your argument into string, e.g. with `"" + feature.properties["2020 Total Population"]` or

```js
`${feature.properties["2020 Total Population"]}`
```

Comment: Ah, that makes logical sense and was confirmed upon implementing your fix. Gracias!